# var_dump($_FILES) result in blank ["type"] for specific image fiile

Tags: php, file-upload

I have an image taken from an older digital camera, around 4MB in size and type "image/jpeg".

When I submit it through a form and look at `var_dump($_FILES);` the array is as follows:

```
array(1) { 
    ["userfile"]=> array(5) { 
        ["name"]=> string(12) "IMGP0004.JPG" 
        ["type"]=> string(0) "" 
        ["tmp_name"]=> string(0) "" 
        ["error"]=> int(1) 
        ["size"]=> int(0) 
    }
}
```

I'm wondering if there is a reason it isn't picking up the file type and also detecting file size as 0. Other files echo out all correct information.

Comment: Increase the value of upload_max_filesize  directive in php.ini

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The `error` property is set to `1`, which means

> Value: 1; The uploaded file exceeds the upload_max_filesize directive in php.ini.

The error codes are explained [here](http://www.php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.errors.php).

Comment: Thanks Pekka. For anyone else changing their upload_max_filesize in php.ini, just remember to restart Apache for changes to take effect.